# Android program design fault

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I am currently developing kind of a Database application for android. However, since the amount of entries is quite low, I don't feel like I need to use a Sqlite database. 
Now, I currently have the "reading" from the save file in the `onCreate()` method. 
But this also loads the file new when I turn the phone from horizontal to vertical display mode, which though it does not affect performance in a huge way, since I don't have that many entries, still bothers me, as I would like to do it the proper way.

What would the "correct" way to do this be?

```
private TableLayout tblLayout;

private ArrayList<Entry> listOfEntries;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);

    // this basically populates my ArrayList
    listOfEntries = readFromFile(saveFile);

    setContentView(tblLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your to your Activity's manifest node:( where you've declared the activity in the AndroidManifest file):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

It will prevent from calling the onCreate() again, when the device rotates. This way you will prevent from reading it again on orientation change.

Then. in your activity if you override `onConfigurationChanged()` method if you want to make any specific changes, which should occur on changing orientation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
}
```

There are many threads which can advice you how to deal with orientation change like:

[Android orientation change calls onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097909/android-orientation-change-calls-oncreate)

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

[Avoid restarting threads on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053270/avoid-restarting-threads-on-orientation-change)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! However, the overriden `onConfigurationChanged()` you provided doesn't do anything so it can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnCreate()` from `Application` class to do your file loading. This method executes only once.

**[code samples]**

*MyApplication.java*

```
package com.example.sunday;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public ArrayList<Entry> listOfEntries;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        readFromFile(savedFile);
    }
    //define your readFromFile(File f) somewhere here
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.sunday;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Entry> listOfEntries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyApplication a = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        listOfEntries = a.listOfEntries;
    }
}
```

in *AndroidManifest.xml* you have to "register" your MyApplication class:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication"
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution is:

```
private TableLayout tblLayout;
private ArrayList<Entry> listOfEntries;
private boolean isFileLoaded = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);

    if(!isFileLoaded){
        listOfEntries = readFromFile(saveFile);
        isFileLoaded = true;
    }

    setContentView(tblLayout);
}
```

but I will still use Application class as in [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637725/1168820) - it gives me opportunity to "hide" readFromFile method in a different java file, making my Activity.java file cleaner.